# Is there a difference between calling BeginTransaction from the SQLConnection object or from the SqlCommand object?

Tags: c#, transactions

So I have this sql from c# to insert purchase info into a table (sql server 2005), and purchase items (multiple) into another table.

I would like the 2 insert statements to be run in a transaction by calling BeginTransaction.

I notice that I can do it either from the SqlConnection object or SqlCommand object. My guts tells me that I should do it through the connection object, as I will be using 1 command object for each insert, but they both share the same connection.

Am I right?

In general is there a difference between the two?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you propose to start transactions on the SqlCommand. Could you give a code example?

Comment: Please take a look: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10223/Using-Transactions-in-ADO-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10223/Using-Transactions-in-ADO-NET)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a SqlTransaction from the connection (BeginTransaction), then pass this in to the each SqlCommand object. There's a constructor that takes the SqlTransaction as parameter or just set the SqlCommand.Transaction property.

Something like: (sorry formatting difficult on iPad)

```
var tran = db.BeginTransaction();
try {

  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(...., tran);
  // or.  
  com.Transaction=tran;

  // do the work, eg execute SQL 

  // finally commit the changes
  tran.Commit();
}
catch
{
  tran.Rollback();
}
```

Comment: The variable tran will be unavailable in catch, you should put it outside of try.